# Vaadin add icon for error message component

Tags: vaadin, textfield, error-messaging

I am wondering if it's possible to add an icon to the error message component that is triggered by Binder.

```java
TextField usernameField = new TextField();

binder.forField(usernameField)
    .asRequired("Please fill this field")
    .withValidator(s -> s.length() > 3, "Username must contain at least 4 characters")
    .withValidator(s -> s.length() < 12, "Username must contain less than 12 characters")
    .bind(User::getUsername, User::setUsername);
```

**Actual**
[image: Actual]

**Expected**
[image: Expected]

---

I found this workaround, but maybe exists a more native way to do this. The problem is that it's required to have an error image `.png` to display the icon, which I don't really like so much. The other issue is that I can't set color for icon, I need to have 2 identical icons but with different colors(warning=yellow, error=red).

```css
vaadin-text-field::part(error-message)::before {
    content: url('/icons/error-icon.jpg');
    margin-right: 4px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no API for doing that, and even if there was, I would still recommend a CSS-based approach, as it's much more lightweight.

As for setting a different color for the icon, you should do that through a classname on the field `addClassName("warning");`)

Then you have a few different options for how to change the color of the icon:

A) Switch to a different image when the classname is applied:

```
vaadin-text-field.warning::part(error-message)::before {
  content: url('/icons/warning-icon.jpg');
}
```

B) Use a font icon instead of a bitmap, e.g. with FontAwesome you could do something like this:

```
vaadin-text-field::part(error-message)::before {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 6 Free";
    content: '\f5b3';
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Different color for warning state */
vaadin-text-field.warning::part(error-message)::before {
    color: rgb(156, 122, 0);
}
```

Or you could use the built-in Lumo Icons font:

```
vaadin-text-field::part(error-message)::before {
    font-family: "lumo-icons";
    content: var(--lumo-icons-error);
    display: inline-block;
}
```

C) Use an SVG image as a `mask` over a background color you can change.